# WordPress plugin development theme issue

Tags: plugin-development, css

Developed the WordPress plugin using https://materializecss.com/ framework , Once plugin activated it will automatically create 4 pages in WordPress. Here I'm facing one issue with WordPress multiple theme. In some of the theme they are directly writing CSS for the elements without using any classes or id. For example: body{ margin:0; padding:0;} button{width:40px} Like this they have done because of this its affecting all the pages created by plugin. For temporary solution override those styles from plugin itself. But its differ based on themes can't able to override each and every CSS properties.

Anyone know how to solve this issue please post your answer here. Because of this issue still plugin not pushed to WordPress.Org market place.

Comment: You need to rethink your approach entirely. WordPress and themes already have extensive CSS. You can't use a framework that expects to be the lowest level of CSS because it's going to conflict with themes. You need to just write the bare minimum CSS you need for your plugin to work, and write it in such a way that's compatible with as many themes as possible. There's no magic trick, you just need to know how to use CSS well and test thoroughly.

Comment: Thanks for your response jacob.Currently its compatible for 10 themes exactly is that fine for to submit the plugin in wordpress.org ?

Comment: You would need to ask the review team. I don't know if there's a minimum requirement, but if it doesn't work at all with any other themes then there's a problem.

Comment: Jacob I'm using short codes , the plugin main concept is, it will  connect rest api for booking flow. Its online rental portal, is there any other way we can develop? Do you have any idea. I need solution from this theme css issue. Because of this for more that 40 user updating plugin manually. If new version is developed means need to update manually to each and every users. Thanks jacob for your response.

Comment: Typically you *want* the theme to provide the styles for any content added by plugins. One option may be to wrap everything inside one overarching container, say a `<div>`, with a particular class for your plugin. That way your plugin's styling - whatever minimal amount needs to be added for it to work at all - can target anything within that class.